# Creating matrix with moving group identifier

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to create a matrix with `180*12` rows and `12` columns in R. I'm not sure what the specific codes for R to create something like this.

```
Column 1: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,..................0
Column 2: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,..................0
Column 3: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,..................0
```

Ect. with the same pattern until Column12. Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: erm..what pattern is that exactly? Would help if you said it. "Column `i` has 12 '1's starting at row `(i - 1)*12 + 1` ?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apply(diag(12), 2, rep, each=12)
```

A shorter example:

```
apply(diag(3), 2, rep, each=2)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    0    0
## [2,]    1    0    0
## [3,]    0    1    0
## [4,]    0    1    0
## [5,]    0    0    1
## [6,]    0    0    1
```

Another very similar solution, without an explicit `apply`:

```
matrix(rep(diag(12), each=12), ncol=12)
```

This works because `as.vector(diag(N))` is a vector with `N` 1's, each separated by `N` 0'.  An example with diag(3), each=2, ncol=3 is identical to the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Just for laughs, here is a `model.matrix` version of @MatthewLundberg's answer:

```
model.matrix( ~ rep(factor(1:3),each=2) - 1)

a <- rep(factor(1:3),each=2)
model.matrix( ~ a - 1)

  a1 a2 a3
1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  1  0
4  0  1  0
5  0  0  1
6  0  0  1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$a
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Or all in one line:

```
model.matrix( ~ rep(factor(1:3),each=2) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

And the `class.ind` approach from `nnet`

```
class.ind(rep(factor(1:3),each=2))
```